# What happened to the documentation?

Tags: spring

Where is the documentation for Spring 4? It is nowhere to be found. Please provide a link somewhere. Most people are still using Spring 4.

I have tried to go to spring.io website and click DOCS link at the top. It only displays the "current" documentation, which is for Spring 5.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.13.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/

Answer (score 0):

You can find all SPring documentations for each Spring version [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/). If you want some version to be displayed as a website go to spring-framework-reference/html/ directory under the selected version